How to get in sync when working with someone knew and doesn't have a schedule
Someone who owns a small managed IT company wants to hire me. He wants to hire me as a contractor for part time work. I know it's not good, but I've already started working without having a comprehensive contract. This happened because I thought we were meeting to go over the business details but instead he jumped right into the work. We did agree on my pay rate, but basically nothing else. I've asked him questions about what the schedule is like or what he expects my availability to be like. Basically he said he doesn't have an answer.
Here is an example of what is messing me up (taking parts from different scenarios). I wake up to a message from him asking me to call him when I'm available. I call and he tells me he has work for me and to connect with a specific client. I call the client but get voice mail. I call again in 15 minutes and get voice mail. Now what? How should I invoice this? I prioritize paid work highly and am wondering if I should cancel the plans I made for the day.
Also is it normal to invoice for travel time? He said most of the work is remote but sometimes it's in a different city. Is it normal to invoice for on boarding tasks and getting connected to their system? For example installing required apps, setting up the VPN and email connections etc.
I know the answers to these questions are things I should get from the person I'm working with. But I feel like each time I've tried to ask he has (unintentionally) not answered.

Some of these questions are ones that you answer for you and you tell the client, not ask them.
Do I invoice for when the client asks me to do something such as contact a customer, and I can't get through to them? That is something you decide for how you want to run your business, and you add that to your standard "how I do business" that you hand to your client in the first meeting. "I will bill with a minimum of 15 minutes on every action that you request of me even if circumstances prevent immediate success."
You are not an employee where your boss tells you how to operate. Think of how a lawyer operates. They bill on everything. If you want to be a professional that your clients are hiring, then you get to tell the prospect how you will operate.

Makes sense. Would you suggest I have these details written into a contract, just mention it to him, or just invoice as such? For example should I discuss with him I will bill minimum of 15 minutes per request or just send the bill?

@PoliteShark Tell him as soon as possible in writing. In that way, they can't complain as much when they get the invoice.

I'm an independent IT consultant and I have clients that engage with me to provide managed IT services, and I have clients that call me on an as needed basis. There are several things to address here and these are some of my thoughts on your situation.

This person is your client. It appears that he can't or won't commit to a specific work schedule for you. In cases where I have clients that won't or can't make a commitment to me (because they call me on an as needed basis), I provide them with my availability as such; I will return your call or respond to your email within one business day. If this is an emergency I'll respond to you within 4 hours which will entail invoking my "emergency service rates" (which is 1.5 times my standard hourly rate). - I do this because lacking a commitment from the client, I need to be working for other clients or looking for other work. I don't get paid to be on call or be at the beck and call of clients who may or may not call me to perform work for them. If the client has an emergency that necessitates my immediate attention then they need to pay a premium for that attention because it is likely that I'll need to step away from performing paying work for another client, which is an inconvenience and  a disruption to me and to my other client.

I bill for any and all work I perform for a client. That includes phone calls, emails, onboarding, travel, etc. If I am doing any of those things for a client that means that I can't be earning money from other clients, therefore the client I'm doing those things for needs to pay me for my time. My clients don't work for free, and neither do I.

You are in the "you" business. This means making sure you have contracts in place and it means setting your clients expectations in terms of your availability and compensation.

This is the most important item. I don't engage with any client prior to having a legally binding contract in place. The contract should lay out specifics regarding compensation, payment schedules, availability, what work is covered under the contract, what work is not covered under the contract, your responsibilities, their responsibilities, etc., etc.

Equally important, if you're an independent contractor, and you're in the USA, make sure that you have the correct and appropriate business insurance. For you this probably means professional liability insurance and general liability insurance.


